# JPanel Observer

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern

I created a game in a separate panel class from the GUI main class. I am trying to find a way to update the score and level text fields found inside the GUI main class, when a method inside the panel class is executed. I tried to use the observer design pattern but the panel class already extends `JPanel` and can only extend one item. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Do you have some code to go with the question?

Comment: "when a method inside the jPanel class is executed." First of all, are you sure that method belongs to the jPanel and not to the GUI main class or to a generic Engine class (that could extend `Observable`)? Your solution may be as easy as moving your method to a more suitable location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of observer pattern does not require that you extends your new JPanel class. You should to define the interface(s) and implement that/those interface(s) in your class.
I recommend to you take a look on [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial).

Comment: I'll have a look. Is there an alternative for using the observer pattern?

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, you're asking if there's another DP similar to observer? Or you just want another example of implementation of observer pattern?

Comment: You have few DP similar to Observer, but you must analyze your requirements and produced code, and after that decide which DP will be used. You can use Guava's EventBus (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=guava+observer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), or if you have need to implement cross app communication pattern - there is publish-subscribe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).